# How can I determine the relationship of C integer type MIN/MAXes in the preprocessor?

Tags: c, integer, c-preprocessor, primitive-types

I’m trying to determine the relationship of a given compiler’s integer types’ sizes using the preprocessor. My requirement is that I have two types, one of which is unsigned, and one of which is a signed type capable of storing *every* positive number that said unsigned type can store. i.e. I have to ensure that my `ll_ssize` type can store at least as many positive *and* negative integers as the `ll_usize` can store.

Unfortunately, the exact relationships of `long long` and `long` and `int` aren’t defined by the C standards; on [some machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Specific_data_models) (such as LP64 machines), the data storage of a `long` is going to be exactly equivalent to a `long long`.

Thus, I have to use the preprocessor to attempt to determine the largest possible type that *also* has a single *larger* type available; the unsigned version of that type becomes `ll_usize`, and the signed version of the larger type becomes `ll_ssize`.

Here is the code I’m using now:

```
#if defined(ULONG_MAX) && defined(LLONG_MIN) && defined(LLONG_MAX) && \
    LLONG_MIN <= -(ULONG_MAX) && ULONG_MAX <= LLONG_MAX
  typedef   unsigned    long int   ll_usize;
  typedef   signed long long int   ll_ssize;
#elif defined(UINT_MAX) && defined(LONG_MIN) && defined(LONG_MAX) && \
      LONG_MIN <= -(UINT_MAX) && UINT_MAX <= LONG_MAX
  typedef   unsigned    int   ll_usize;
  typedef   signed long int   ll_ssize;
#else
  typedef   signed int   ll_usize;
  typedef   signed int   ll_ssize;
#endif
```

Now, on to my problem. I can’t preform casts in preprocessor expressions, but it seems that `ULONG_MAX` is being incorrectly converted, as my compiler (`clang` on Mac OS 10.6 X Snow Leopard) spits out the following warning:

```
Source/Paws.o/Core/ll.h:21:15: warning: left side of operator converted from
      negative value to unsigned: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775808
    LLONG_MIN <= -(ULONG_MAX) && ULONG_MAX <= LLONG_MAX
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Does anybody know of a way for me to work around this conversion error? Or, preferably, a better solution to the overall problem, because I really dislike these ugly preprocessor expressions.

**Edit:** I should also point out why I’m doing this, instead of just using the largest signed type available: I don’t want to waste the memory space for all of those negative integers, when I’m never going to be storing negative numbers. Specifically, the unsigned type (`ll_usize`) is used for the stored indexes into a linked list; however, some functions that operate on the linked list can take negative index arguments, and work from the opposite end of the linked list: those functions are declared to take `ll_ssize` instead. The waste is acceptable as the arguments to those functions; however, the waste for the indexes on the *actual lists* stored in the system is not.

Comment: I don't have any solution to offer, but I can tell you're going to have a hard time doing -2^64 with most C preprocessors.

Comment: I didn't look close enough to formulate an answer, but, using the unary - operator on an unsigned number is meaningless.  It is unsigned, it doesn't have any negative values.  The conversion that the compiler needs make to keep its sense makes it barf.

Comment: Yeah, that’s the problem I’m trying to solve. I can’t cast in the preprocessor; hence I need some sort of way to make this math ‘legal.’ Obviously attempting to provide a negative representation of the largest-available type is going to be … #fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `-(LLONG_MIN+1) > (ULONG_MAX-1)` ?

Comment: Hm! That gets rid of the warning, but I’m not sure I understand why *both* of them need a ±1…

Comment: because without the +1 on the LLONG_MIN then LLONG_MIN > LLONG_MAX, the -1 just balances the equation :)

Comment: Damn. That’s a genius solution. +1 makes it fit, -1 makes it valid again. I’d give you raw reputation if I could, for that. d-:

Comment: For anyone interested, this completely solved my problem, and elegantly, too: http://github.com/elliottcable/Paws.o/commit/fdfeacc1334bd42214ae9a84c737520fedf681d5

Comment: This actually only works if the processor uses 2s complement to store ints.  Some DSPs I've used use 1s complement.

Comment: Joel: Do you have a better solution? Or a fix for this one?

Comment: You could make it >= rather than just >, there is still a slight edge case but I cannot think what actual integer representation you would need to have to make it an actual issue. I suppose technical anything is possible in a world where these things are terribly concrete.

Comment: What about balancing by two instead of one? Wouldn’t that fit in *all* the various negative integer representations? At least, a quick glance at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Comparison_table makes me think it would work… but I’m no expert /-:

Answer (score 0):

How about `ULONG_MAX < LLONG_MAX`?

Forget that "less-than-or-equal" stuff, you want it to be *strictly less than*.

Comment: Nah, it should be less than or equal to: the signed type can store everything between (-UNSIGNED_TYPE_MAX) and (+UNSIGNED_TYPE_MAX), because I need to be able to positively- and negatively-index every element.

I should mention, that also doesn’t get rid of the conversion error.

Comment: Is it really honestly important to support systems where `ulong` is 63 bits?

Comment: This is targeted at many, many, many platforms; I expect to support 32bit machines, possibly 128bit machines, as well as extremely-restricted embedded applications and such.

On top of that, I’m just curious what the correct solution is at this point d-: